# How Do I Install Quick 'n Easy Web Builder 2

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, software-center, software-installation, paid-applications

I purchased Quick 'n Easy Web Builder 2 from Ubuntu Software Center.

But Ubuntu Software Center could not / will not install it.

I looked at [software-center.ubuntu.com](http://software-center.ubuntu.com) and I can see the PPA fingerprint and license key.

How do I install Quick 'n Easy Web Builder 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick 'n Easy Web Builder 2** can be easily installed using a terminal.

- First open a terminal
- Then type (or copy & Paste) the following command and press enter

  `sudo apt-get install quick-n-easy-web-builder-2`
- Enter your password when asked.
- Once installed you can find Quick 'n Easy Web Builder 2 in the applications menu 
  (or by using the dash on Ubuntu).

By default this installs the 30 day trial version, but you have the option to enter your Licence key each time you start the application.

You can find your License Key at the bottom of the email confirming your purchase from Ubuntu Software Centre.